# Doubt in verilog

Tags: digital-logic, verilog

I have a doubt what is 4'd0 meaning in this program?

```
// Johnson Counter

module johnson_counter( out,reset,clk);
input clk,reset;
output [3:0] out; 
reg [3:0] q; 

always @(posedge clk)
begin
    if(reset)
       q=4'd0;
    else
    begin 
        q[3]<=q[2];
        q[2]<=q[1];
        q[1]<=q[0];
        q[0]<=(~q[3]);
    end
end

endmodule
```

Comment: literal constant, 4 bits wide, decimal value 0 - see https://sutherland-hdl.com/pdfs/verilog_2001_ref_guide.pdf section 4.11 Literal Integer Numbers

Comment: Google 'literals in Verilog'

Answer (score 1):

`4’d0` means a vector constant that is 4 bits wide, decimal value of 0.

In this code it is used to initialize the 4-bit reg variable `q` to all zeroes in the `reset` statement.

If it were `3’d0`, only the lower 3 bits would be reset.

This bit-width characteristic of Verilog is important to keep in mind. Careful Verilog coding style pays close attention to how Verilog handles constants vs. vector widths. Subtle, hard-to-find bugs can happen to the unwary.